# What is this invariant graph?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity, graph-colorings

Let $G$ be a simple graph (finite or infinite), $[n]\mathrel{:=}\{1,...,n\}$. Define the function:
$$\varepsilon_n(G)\mathrel{:=}\min_\phi{\lvert{\operatorname{dom} (\phi)}\rvert},$$
where $\phi$ is the partial function $\phi:V(G)\to[n]$ such that $\forall x,y\in[n]$, $x\neq y$, $\exists u,v\in V(G)$: $\phi(u)=x$, $\phi(v)=y$, $uv \in E(G)$ and $\forall u,v\in \operatorname{dom}(\phi)$, $u\neq v$, $\phi(u)=\phi(v) \implies uv\notin E(G) $.
I need information about this function, but I don't know where to search.
Intuitively, one can think of this function as the minimum number of characters we can write to express the inequality of $n$ numbers if we place them on the nodes of a graph and place symbols of inequality on the edges. It's obvious that $0 \leq \varepsilon_n(G) \leq v(G) $,
$$\varepsilon_n(K_m)=\begin{cases}n,\ m\geq n\\0,\ m < n. \end{cases}$$
In particular, I am interested in the values ​​of $\varepsilon_n(\mathbb{Z}_G)$, where $\mathbb{Z}_G $ is the undirected infinite graph such that $V(\mathbb{Z}_G )= \mathbb{Z} $, and $E(\mathbb{Z}_G)=\{(i,j)\in \mathbb{Z}^2\mathrel: i+1=j \}$.
It's clear that $\varepsilon_n(\mathbb{Z}_G) \neq 0 $ for all $n$, but I have no rigorous proof of this statement. I am also interested in the complexity of calculating $ \varepsilon_n(G) $ in the general case, but I do not understand how not to iterate over many $\phi$. I think that $\varepsilon_n(G) \in \mathrm{FNP}$.

Comment: I don't think "$\varepsilon_n(G) \in \mathrm{FNP}$" literally makes sense, but perhaps this sort of shorthand for "the problem of computing $\varepsilon_n(G)$ belongs to $\mathrm{FNP}$" is common.

Comment: By $v(G)$ do you mean $n(G)$, the number of vertices? When $n\gt m$ why isn't $\varepsilon_n(K_m)$ undefined or $\infty$?>

Comment: @bof, yes, $v(G)$ is a number of vertices.  It seemed to me that  $\varepsilon_n(G)= 0$ would be correct if there are no required colorings . I guess I want to keep the boundaries $0\leq \varepsilon_n(G)\leq v(G)   $  Maybe I was wrong.

Comment: Have you noticed the relationship of your question to the concept of the [achromatic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_coloring) of a graph?

Comment: @bof,  strange, but this is the first time I hear about the achromatic number and it definitely has relationship of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rephrasing, given $G$ and $n$ you're looking for the smallest subset $V' \subseteq V$ of the vertices of $G$ such that the subgraph $G'$ induced by $V'$ has a vertex colouring $\phi$ on $n$ colours for which every pair of colours $c \neq d$ has an edge between those colours and there is no edge between two vertices of the same colour.

For your particular case of interest, when $n$ is odd we can colour a subchain of $\mathbb{Z}_G$ in the sequence of colours of an Eulerian path on $K_n$ to find that $\varepsilon_n(\mathbb{Z}_G) = \binom{n}{2} + 1$. When $n$ is even, $\varepsilon_n(\mathbb{Z}_G) = \binom{n}{2} + \frac{n-2}{2} + 1$ by a similar argument, as bof correctly pointed out in a comment improving the earlier claim of this answer: the addition of $\frac{n-2}{2}$ edges is necessary and sufficient for an Eulerian trace to exist.

Comment: In other words, $\varepsilon_n(G)$ is the minimum order of an induced subgraph of $G$ whose [achromatic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_coloring) is $n$, with the weird stipulation that $\varepsilon_n(G)=0$ if there is no such subgraph.

Comment: Doesn't your argument for even $n$ show that $\varepsilon_n(\mathbb Z_G)=1+\binom n2+\frac{n-2}2=\frac{n^2}2$ in that case? By adding $\frac{n-2}2$ new edges to $K_n$ you get a (multi-)graph with only two vertices of odd degree, so it has an Eulerian trail.

Comment: @bof, good point.